# Не получается программно включить камеру

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

не получается вызвать стандартное приложение "камера" своего андроид устройства.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
```

в чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@monobogdan предоставил не совсем корректный ответ. Подробнее о том как взаимодействовать с камерой можно прочитать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). То есть вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
```

Также несколько комментариев по поводу вашего кода. Вам обязательно нужно вызвать `startActivityForResult()`, так как вы наверняка хотите получить какой то результат после того как запустите камеру. `startActivity()`же после возвращения в ваше приложение ничего не вернет. Если есть возможность задать параметры обьекта в конструкторе то лучше сдлеать это сразу а не передавать его через сеттер. А NPE у вас вылетал потому что вы указываете не тот флаг в интенте. Надеюсь Вам это поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Основываясь на приведенном вами коде, могу сказать что вы забыли startActivity

Вам необходимо вызвать его после инициализации Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
startActivity(intent);
```

Так же попробуйте LaunchComponent.

Пример здесь:

[Вопрос на android.stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268060/opening-system-application-using-intent)

Comment: showActivity() - нет такого метода. 
а со startActivity() - приложение падает с ошибкой: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON (has extras) }

Comment: @S.TertJ, попробуйте из PackageManager получать Intent и запускать так как в примере по ссылке.